# Deleying js animation

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to delay the animation that starts when the user hovers over the element.
I have tried multiple solutions, and none of them worked.

I have tried animation delay, keyframe delay, transition delay, even targeted the element and added inline style animation delay and none of them worked.
Please help.
Thank you very much.

```js
const rotateForwardAnimationName = 'rotate-forward';
const rotateBackwardAnimationName = 'rotate-backward';

const states = {
  forward: 'forward',
  backward: 'backward',
  rotatingForward: 'rotatingForward',
  rotatingBackward: 'rotatingBackward',
};

const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('polaroid');

const stateMap = new Map();

for (const element of elements) {
  stateMap.set(element, states.backward);

  element.addEventListener('animationstart', (e) => {
    if (e.animationName === rotateForwardAnimationName)
      stateMap.set(element, states.rotatingForward);
    if (e.animationName === rotateBackwardAnimationName)
      stateMap.set(element, states.rotatingBackward);
    onStateUpdate(element);
  });

  element.addEventListener('animationend', (e) => {
    if (e.animationName === rotateForwardAnimationName)
      stateMap.set(element, states.forward);
    if (e.animationName === rotateBackwardAnimationName)
      stateMap.set(element, states.backward);
    onStateUpdate(element);
  });

  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () =>
    onStateUpdate(element)
  );

  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>
    onStateUpdate(element)
  );
}

function onStateUpdate(element) {
  const hovered = element.matches(':hover');
  const state = stateMap.get(element);
  if (state === states.forward && !hovered) rotateBackward(element);
  if (state === states.backward && hovered) rotateForward(element);
}

function rotateBackward(element) {
  element.style.animation = rotateBackwardAnimationName + ' 2s forwards';
}

function rotateForward(element) {
  element.style.animation = rotateForwardAnimationName + ' 2s forwards';
}
```

```css
.polaroid {
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px 15px 100px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: 2%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #aaaaaa;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}

@keyframes rotate-forward {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-8deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-backward {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-8deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="polaroid">
  <p class="caption">Just a basic explanation of the picture.</p>
</div>

<div class="polaroid">
  <p class="caption">Just a basic explanation of the picture.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to success. You just forgot to add the delay. I added a delay of 1 second.

```
element.style.animation = rotateBackwardAnimationName + ' 2s forwards 1s';
```

```js
const rotateForwardAnimationName = 'rotate-forward';
const rotateBackwardAnimationName = 'rotate-backward';

const states = {
  forward: 'forward',
  backward: 'backward',
  rotatingForward: 'rotatingForward',
  rotatingBackward: 'rotatingBackward',
};

const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('polaroid');

const stateMap = new Map();

for (const element of elements) {
  stateMap.set(element, states.backward);

  element.addEventListener('animationstart', (e) => {
    if (e.animationName === rotateForwardAnimationName)
      stateMap.set(element, states.rotatingForward);
    if (e.animationName === rotateBackwardAnimationName)
      stateMap.set(element, states.rotatingBackward);
    onStateUpdate(element);
  });

  element.addEventListener('animationend', (e) => {
    if (e.animationName === rotateForwardAnimationName)
      stateMap.set(element, states.forward);
    if (e.animationName === rotateBackwardAnimationName)
      stateMap.set(element, states.backward);
    onStateUpdate(element);
  });

  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () =>
    onStateUpdate(element)
  );

  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>
    onStateUpdate(element)
  );
}

function onStateUpdate(element) {
  const hovered = element.matches(':hover');
  const state = stateMap.get(element);
  if (state === states.forward && !hovered) rotateBackward(element);
  if (state === states.backward && hovered) rotateForward(element);
}

function rotateBackward(element) {
  element.style.animation = rotateBackwardAnimationName + ' 2s forwards 1s';
}

function rotateForward(element) {
  element.style.animation = rotateForwardAnimationName + ' 2s forwards 1s';
}
```

```css
.polaroid {
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px 15px 100px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  border-radius: 2%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #aaaaaa;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}

@keyframes rotate-forward {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-8deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-backward {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-8deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="polaroid">
  <p class="caption">Just a basic explanation of the picture.</p>
</div>

<div class="polaroid">
  <p class="caption">Just a basic explanation of the picture.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have miss explained myself. I want the animation only start when the user stays hovered on the element for a certain time. I got it confused with delay because, with my previous attempt, I did it that way.(That code didn't work out the way I wanted it. it was just simple CSS).